# Integral involving minimum

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

How can I show that: 
$\int_0^t min(s,u)\phi_u du +\int_0^s min(t,u) \phi_u du = \int_0^t \int_0^s min(u,v) \phi_u \phi_v du dv =0$
when I know: $s \phi_s=\phi_s \int_0^s \phi_u u du$ for all $s \geq 0$